# sed: hold pattern and rearrange line

Tags: regex, variables, sed, awk

I am not sure if I can do this purely with sed:

I am trying to rearrange lines like this

```
GF:001,GF:00012,GF:01223<TAB>XXR
GF:001,GF:00012,GF:01223,GF:0666<TAB>XXXR3
```

to

```
GF:001<TAB>XXR
GF:00012<TAB>XXR
GF:01223<TAB>XXR
GF:001<TAB>XXXR3
GF:00012<TAB>XXXR3
GF:01223<TAB>XXXR3
GF:0666<TAB>XXXR3
```

Anyone any hints? The cardinality of GF:XXXX is alternating as the length of GF:XXXX is.

I am stuck with `sed -n '
'/\(XX.*\)$/' {
s/,/\t\1\n/ 
}' input` but I cannot reference to the originally matched pattern in the first place. any ideas? cheers!

Update: 
I think it is not possible to do this with just using sed. So I used perl to do this:

```
perl -e 'open(IN, "< file");
while (<IN>) {
    @a = split(/\t/);
    @gos = split(/,/, $a[0]);
    foreach (@gos) {
      print $_."\t".$a[1];
    }
close( IN );' > output
```

But if anyone knows a way to solve this just with `sed` please post it here...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It can be done in `sed`, though I probably would use Perl (or Awk or Python) to do it.

I claim no elegance for this solution, but brute force and ignorance sometimes pays off.  I created a file called, unoriginally, `sed.script` containing:

```
/\(GF:[0-9]*\),\(.*\)<TAB>\(.*\)/{
:redo
s/\(GF:[0-9]*\),\(.*\)<TAB>\(.*\)/\1<TAB>\3@@@@@\2<TAB>\3/
h
s/@@@@@.*//
p
x
s/.*@@@@@//
t redo
d
}
```

I ran it as:

```
sed -f sed.script input
```

where `input` contained the two lines shown in the question.  It produced the output:

```
GF:001<TAB>XXR
GF:00012<TAB>XXR
GF:01223<TAB>XXR
GF:001<TAB>XXXR3
GF:00012<TAB>XXXR3
GF:01223<TAB>XXXR3
GF:0666<TAB>XXXR3
```

(I took the liberty of deliberately misinterpreting `<TAB>` to be a 5-character sequence instead of a single tab character; you can easily fix the answer to handle an actual tab character instead.)

Explanation of the `sed` script:

- Find lines with more than one occurrence of `GF:nnn` separated by commas (we do not need to process lines that contain a single such occurrence).  Do the rest of the script only on such lines.  Anything else is passed through (printed) unchanged.
- Create a label so we can branch back to it
- Split the line into 3 remembered parts.  The first part is the initial GF information; the second part is any other GF information; the third part is the field after the `<TAB>`.  Replace this with the first field, `<TAB>`, third field, implausible marker pattern (`@@@@@`), second field, `<TAB>`, third field.
- Copy the modified line to the hold space.
- Delete the marker pattern to the end.
- Print.
- Swap the hold space into the pattern space.
- Remove everything up to and including the marker pattern.
- If we've done any work, go back to the `redo` label.
- Delete what's left (it was printed already).
- End of script block.

This is a simple loop that reduces the number of the patterns by one on each iteration.

Comment: really impressive! i thought sed was not powerful enough to do loops but if you have a GOTO constructor you can mimic a loop. thanks for the proof Jonathan!

Comment: Ah yes, the highly sought-after GOTO construct - a software engineers dream :-).

Answer (score 3):

You can do it straightforwardly with awk:

```
$ awk '{gsub(/,/, "\t" $NF "\n");print}' input
```

In this case, we just replace the comma by a tab concatenated with the last field (`NF` stores the number of fields of a record; `$NF` gets the `NF`th field) concatenated with a newline. Then, print the result.

It can be solved with sed, too, in a way similar but IMHO a bit better than the Jonathan solution (which is pretty sophisticated, I should remark).

```
sed -n '
:BEGIN
 h
 s/,.*<TAB>/<TAB>/
 p
 x
 s/^[^,]*,//
t BEGIN' input
```

Here, we define a label in the beginning of the script:

```
:BEGIN
```

Then we copy the content of the pattern space to the hold space:

```
h
```

Now, we replace everything from the first comma until the tab with only a tab:

```
 s/,.*<TAB>/<TAB>/
```

We print the result...

```
p
```

...and retrieve the content of the hold space:

```
x
```

Since we printed the first line - which contains the first `GF:XXX` pattern followed by the final `XXR` pattern - we remove the first `GF:XXX` pattern from the line:

```
 s/^[^,]*,//
```

If a replacement is executed, we branch to the beginning of script:

```
t BEGIN
```

And everything is applied again to the same line, except that now this line does not have the first `GF:XXX` pattern anymore. OTOH, if no replacement is made, then the processing of the current line is done and we do not jump to the beginning anymore.

Comment: awk solution was fast `real    0m6.496s user    0m1.555s sys     0m0.109s`
sed solution slower `real    0m27.177s user    0m23.080s sys    0m0.129s`
for a 28k lines file

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, actually, since sed should iterate over each instance of the pattern in the line. I posted a sed solution because it was in the specification but it is not probably the best solution for the case. Anyway, I think the awk solution is better, in fact, but I found this problem an awesome sed exercise :)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't strictly want sed, awk is good at doing this:

```
awk -F'\t|,' '{ i=1; do { printf("%s\t%s\n",$i,$NF); i++;}  while ( i<NF ); }' inputfile
```

Comment: thank you! i've done it via perl... should have a look into `awk` though.

Answer (score 2):

Well it took me 3 hours to do it

`sed -re ':a; s/(GF:[0-9]*[^,]*),([^<]*)(<TAB>[A-Z]*)/\1\3\n\2\3/g;ta; ' file.txt`

Comment: @EdMorton that was because you had 30 years behind that and i had 3 days

Comment: No it's because awk has clear, simple syntax while sed for anything more complicated than simple substitutions on a single line requires the Rosetta Stone, 3 wise men and a batman decoder ring.

Comment: @EdMorton , I really need to make a decision. According your advice , can i finish 90% of tasks with awk alone. I really want to use just one of those so that i can go in detail but am not able to decide which one. If you say that 90% of tasks can be done with awk then i will go with it

Comment: You can finish 100% of text processing tasks in awk alone. grep, sed, etc. can be used slightly faster/easier for **small** tasks, though. Most of the complicated things you can do in awk you can also do in sed but the resulting awk will be clear, simple, quick to write and easy to maintain while the equivalent sed will take orders of magnitude longer to write and will need a complete re-write for even the smallest requirements change. Learn awk - the stuff you SHOULD use sed for is so simple you don't need to put any effort into learning it, you'll just pick it up from a couple of examples.

Comment: I just added an explanation of my awk script for your benefit. Notice that all I'm doing is explaining a couple of the most fundamental awk concepts and from that I expect you're able to understand the script. Compare that to the complexity and specificity of the explanations of the sed scripts on this page and seriously imagine yourself trying to build upon or debug both the awk and the sed scripts. Note: I use sed almost every day so don't think I'm anti-sed, it is a great tool for what it's good at which is simple substitutions on a single line.

Comment: @EdMorton thanks man , i really thank you for that. i always wanted to know the people experience  i will definitely follow your advice. One thing more , Now when do i need to make the decision that i should do that stuff in `awk` or some language like `python`.

Comment: Best i can tell you use perl or python when your manager tells you to due to some corporate decree. For me, when I'm doing non-text-processing jobs I just write it in shell or C but I understand perl and python may have some capabilities that are useful in some domain other than the one in which I work, maybe something to do with web development?

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -F'[,\t]' '{for (i=1;i<NF;i++) print $i"\t"$NF}' file
```

Awk reads one line at a time (by default) and splits the line up into fields. I'm using -F to tell awk to separate the line into fields at each comma or tab. NF is the number of fields in the line, $i is the contents of field number i.